# getAddToCartUrl not working

Tags: checkout, addtocart

I have this button in my custom module:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>"> Add to Cart </a>
```

But I need to use this one:

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')"> <span> Add to Cart</span> </button>
```

But this not working:

```
<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code and let me know its working or not But you can try

Here`<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>` not working, because its your custom module and your block is not extending `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` this class.

If you want to use `<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>` only then extend your block class with `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`

Or If you dont have block class then just write below code in your phtml This is a trick But works

Other solution is that you can write below code also

```
$class  = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract();
echo $class->getAddToCartUrl($product);
```

Comment: With echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product')->getAddToCartUrl($product); not working. I have a phtml file I don't have a class to extend with Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract...

Comment: See My updated answer

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I don't have a Block Class. I have a .phtml file and I call it since my HOME CMS Page.

Comment: bro Add this line in your phtml code `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product')->setProduct($product)->getAddToCartUrl($product);
`  and let me know

Comment: See one more solution for you added in answer

Comment: The last solution not working: Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract in

Comment: And the other also not working :( :( :(

Comment: I'm sorry but nothing works

Comment: So sorry Bro you have to create a block and extend this block and assign block to your phtml this is the only solution